# How to modify the 'apsrev.bst' file to make a "number bib entry" instead of "author name bib entry"?

Tags: bibliographies

[image]

Latex question! My reference is like what the picture shows above, and I used the "apsrev.bst" file. How can I modify this file to make the entry numerical like [2],[3]... instead of [auther name(year)]? To use the "apsrev.bst" file, I samplely used:

```
\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to modify the bibliography style file. It should suffice to insert the instruction `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` in the preamble of the LaTeX document -- and then re-run LaTeX, of course. And, do keep the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apsrev}`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried it, but the entry changes to [C], [B].... still not [1], [2],... I thought I need to modify the style file is because the instruction of the style file says that the entry will be like what shows in the picture. It's better I don't need to modify it. Are there any other suggestions to make the entry numerical?

Comment: @uny - Which document class do you employ?

Comment: I'm writing my thesis, so the document class is special thesis document for my school. Thank you so much. It worked just now.